# The json string I'm sending from javasript throught the function $.ajax() to my http controller funtion is null

Tags: javascript, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-core-webapi

```
    SendData: function () {
            var jasonStr = JSON.stringify(GamePlayedObj);
            console.log(jasonStr);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                async: false,
                url: '@Url.Action("GamesSoFar", "AllCards")',
                dataType: "json",
                data: jasonStr,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
            });
        }

    [Route("Output")]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GamesSoFar(string jasonStr) {
        string j = jasonStr;
        string a = "";
        GameInfo InfoOfTheLastGame = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GameInfo>(jasonStr);
        _context.Add(InfoOfTheLastGame);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        var AllGames = _context.AllGames.Include(g => g.AllGames).ToList();
        return View(AllGames);
    }
```

I'm using the Asp.net core webApi. The parameter I use on my function controller goes null instead of the json string..the j and the a variables are for debbuging reasons any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your code put the `jasonStr` into request body,so you cannot get the data in controller.If you want to get the jasonStr,you can use `[FromBody]` to specify that a parameter or property should be bound using the request body and use `GameInfo jasonStr` rather than `string jasonStr` to bind the data.

Here is a demo worked:

GameInfo:

```
public class GameInfo
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int price { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
<div>
    <button onclick="SendData()">SendData</button>
</div>
@section scripts{
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var GamePlayedObj = {};
        GamePlayedObj.name = "game1";
        GamePlayedObj.price = 10;
        function SendData() {
            var jasonStr = JSON.stringify(GamePlayedObj);
            console.log(jasonStr);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                async: false,
                url: '@Url.Action("GamesSoFar", "AllCards")',
                dataType: "json",
                data: jasonStr,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
            });
        }


    </script>
}
```

Controller:

```
 [Route("Output")]
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult GamesSoFar([FromBody]GameInfo jasonStr)
        {
            string a = "";
            return View("OutPut");
        }
```

Result:

[image]